# Set Field Empty When Change Password in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I want to set empty this field:
[image]

This is my code from _form.php

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'password'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'password'); ?>
</div>
```

how to that, please teach me. Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly set the value to be an empty string like this:

```
<?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password',array(
    'size'=>50,
    'maxlength'=>50,
    'value'=>'',
)); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Where you are starting your form, you can add htmlOptions like this;

```
        'htmlOptions' => array(
            'autocomplete' => 'off'
        )
```

This will disable autocomplete for the whole form. If you just want to do it for a single field, add it to the htmlOptions for that file instead.

Comment: wow, Mr. Joe again. Thanks for answering. I put it on <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50, 'htmlOptions' => array(
            'autocomplete' => 'off'
        ))); ?>

But, nothing change. Am I wrong?? Sorry really I am a newbie

Comment: Try this <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'password',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50, 'autocomplete' => 'off')); ?>

Comment: still nothing happens, sir

Comment: Ok, this could be for one of two reasons. To find out which, can you look at the html code for the password field? It should have an attribute 'autocomplete='off'. Can you copy and paste the code for the password field? The other reason could be that you have some script running on your browser which is overriding the autocomplete setting. Looking at the code for the password field will help to decide which it is.

Comment: <input size="50" maxlength="50" autocomplete="off" name="Admin[password]" id="Admin_password" type="password" value="21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3" />

this is the HTML code. I use Mozilla Firefox

Comment: Ok, so the autocomplete='off' setting is definitely there and set correctly, which probably means that you have some kind of script running in your browser which is overriding the autocomplete setting. You'll need to either try it in a different browser, or have a look at your add-ons and try disabling them one at a time to see if any of them are interfering.

Comment: @gultomicro or you could try checking the settings in your browser, see if you've set it to always remember passwords for your site.

Answer (score 0):

This strange behaviour is happen for me too.

I fix it with javascript code to set the password field value to empty.

Yii code:

```
    <div class="row">    
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'newpassword'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->passwordField($model,'newpassword',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>128,'value'=>'')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'newpassword'); ?>
    </div>
```

Javascript code (I am using jQuery) :

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
    $("#ChangePasswordForm_newpassword").val("");
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo CHtml::passwordField('User[password]','')
```